# Why related row on pivot table is not deleted on polymorphic many to many?

Tags: php, laravel

Tables associated with the models `Post`, `Tag`, `Taggable` are in polymorphic relationship. If I delete a tag then still its `tag_id` may have been used on `taggables` table. Do I have to delete all of its associations manually ?

And what is the role of following code on Taggable model? The code seems to work without it.

```
public function taggables() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using polymorphic relationship when it's not needed?

Comment: Will it be fair to use if I have videos table too which wants to use the tag too. So in that case what would be the answer to above question ?

Answer (score 0):

The code on `Taggable model` is called a relationship, basically when you want to retrieve all `taggables` => `$taggable->taggable` will return all results in `taggables` table.

To be able to delete polymorphic relationship you need to use `detach` from your parent classes, which in this case are `Post` and `Video` => `$post->tags()->detach($tagId)` or `$video->tags()->detach($tagId)`

To add a polymorphic relationship you can use `attach` => `$post->tags()->attach($tagId)` or `$video->tags()->attach($tagId)`

Both functions also can take other parameters, and you can check them out on their [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)